# Question concerning a product of digits algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, decimal-expansion

Define a function $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $ as follows: for a positive integer $n$, we express $n$ in terms of its decimal expansion, say $$n=a_0 + a_1 10 +\cdots +a_d 10^d  $$  We define $f(n)=a_0 a_1 \cdots a_d $.  Note that for each positive integer $n$, there is a positive integer $k$ such that $$f(n)>\cdots>f^k (n)=f^{k+1}(n)=\cdots$$ For the purposes of this question, let's call $k$ the **length** of $n$.  So for example, when $n=2334$, we calculate $$f(2334)=72,\quad f(72)=14,\quad f(14)=4,\quad\text{and}\quad f(4)=4$$ So the length of $2334$ is $3$.  Viewing length as a function on $\mathbb{N}$, is it bounded above?  If not, 
then what is the largest length possible and which integer attains this length?

Comment: The question statement style reminds me [projecteuler.net](https://projecteuler.net), though I can't find the problem I want to remind that asking help is illegal there)

Comment: I came up with the problem on my own.

Comment: [Quick look-up](https://tio.run/##tZHBisIwEIbPzVPEWwoqu1vBZSFPIhICmW4D6TRMIyris3cnEaS9iJfNYTJz@Of7mT9eUzdg8x1pmpy@3YWDVrYK6x9R@Vai9Cgd9xVBOhH3BzyKKlfd29RtIw1OeUzK17IdSPosGBPxhlosRML3caAks6xQwpOSeVrjDPMxoy/wD34wuvznzgco8tVDjjoP3IStjRHQlSkbQ7Mu3gBPPZBNoEKmV7zRHzUasUS45zH@16Z5w6d5ZdSOI/BVg/pqmh3ba0SknEdvL0oFjmW9mUdDFn@hBPYJ@5rfNP0B "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") under $10^7$ gives maximum length is reached on $2677889$ to be $8$. Any thoughts why the length is to be bounded from above?

Comment: It may not be bounded above.  I assumed it was because it became increasingly difficult to avoid digits like 5, 2, and 0 when applying f.  For instance, take n=278834.  Then f(n)=10752.  Since we have 0 as a digit of 10752, we know the next iteration of f will stabilize at 0.

Comment: This [Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_digital_root) may be relevant to your interests.  It is apparently conjectured that there is no number with a **multiplicative persistence** (i.e., "length" in your terminology) greater than $11$; this has been confirmed to numbers up to $10^{20585}$.

Comment: Also [this article](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativePersistence.html) from Wolfram MathWorld.  (That article also uses the terminology "number length," so you are in good company.)

Comment: "Confirmed up to $10^{20585}$" is not as impressive as it sounds; after one step, we get to $2^a 3^b 7^c$ with $\frac a3 + \frac b2 + c \le 20585$, which leaves many fewer possibilities.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: Don't blame the messenger. :-)